# What is the correct way to seal off a fireplace chimney?

Tags: fireplace, chimney

I've seen people say cap it at the top, I've seen people say stuff insulation in the bottom, I've seen people say brick it off at the bottom and seal it at the top. I've also seen all of these strategies criticized, usually because of causing moisture problems.

I've also seen that it depends on if you're in a warm climate or a cold climate... but what if you're in an area that has hot summers and cold winters?

Comment: Is it safe to use as is and do you want the change to be irreversible?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever area you live in I would suggest A minimum of capping the top, then blocking the bottom.

Capping the top prevents moisture like rain from causing problems below. Blocking at the bottom helps future residents from trying to use the fireplace.

I have seen perfectly good chimneys capped because the fireplace was so inefficient, then a new owner DIY a insert and caused thousands in smoke damage.

My current home had a 1930 fireplace with a gorgeous river rock chimney, it was not lined so at first I capped it then removed the chimney.
If I would have left it inplace for the Look I would have blocked it also at the bottom.  Just in case...